# Jquery Exit Popup meanwhile trigger a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow, onbeforeunload

My goal is to trigger a pop up function meanwhile the user is going out from my website.

So I want to show a exit popup and in the background show my pop up at the same time.

I already have found different code on internet but no one works well.

Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function PopUp() { return 'Do you wnat to leave my site?'; }
  function UnPopIt() { /* no data */ }

  $(document).ready(function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = PopUp;
  });
</script>
```

Is it possible to trigger a function like a pop up in the background ?
I am trying this code but it doesn't work :

```
function PopUp()
{
    alert ('Do you wnat to leave my site?'); triggerpopup();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to display two pop up at the same time? the code next to alert will execute only after alert box is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,not very understand your needs,but i can't add a comment right now.
2,suppose you want a selfdefined pop(not another alert),then this goes well

```
function PopUp() { 
  triggerpopup();
  return 'Do you?';
}

function triggerpopup() { 
  console.info('called with default pop') 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = PopUp;    
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering! i can see the exit pop up, but non showing triggerpopup function!